# In R, match data from a string variable across two data frames, and when match is found, merge corresponding rows

Tags: r, string, for-loop, merge, match

I have two data frames df1 (4x4) and df2 (4x1). In each, first variable (i.e. Original_items and Reordered) is string. In df1, V2:V4 are numeric. You can see that in df1 and df2, data in the first variable is arranged in a different order. I need to do the following.

Take 1st element of the df2 'Reordered' variable (i.e. Enjoy holidays.), then search through elements of df1 'Original_items' variable to find the exact match.

When match is found, I need to take the entire row of data associated with the matched element in df1 'Original_items' (i.e."Enjoy holidays.", 4,1,3), and append it beside the same element of df2 'Reordered' variable (i.e. "Enjoy holidays"). I need this output in the new data frame, called df_desired, which should be: "Enjoy holidays.", "Enjoy holidays.", 4, ,1 ,3. Please see below illustration of this example.

When this is done, I would like to repeat this process for each element of the df2 'Reordered'variable, so the final result looks like df_desired table below.

Context of the problem. I have around 2,000 items and 1,000 data points associated with each item. As I need to match items and append data in a predefined way, I am trying to think of an efficient solution.

**EDIT**
It was suggested that I could simply rename items in the "Original Variable". While this is true, it is inconvenient to do for a data frame of more than 2,000 items.

Also, it was mentioned that this question maybe only related to merging. I believe merging is needed here only for elements that have been identified as identical across df1 and df2. Therefore, there are two key questions: 1) how to match string variables in this particular case? 2) how to merge/append rows conditionally, i.e. if they have been matched. Thank you for your input and I would be grateful for your help please

I will mention what I tried and figured out so far. I realised

```
 df1[,1] == df2 [,1] # gives me true or false if rows in column 1 are the 
                       same in both data frames. I tried to set up a double loop, but unsuccessfully   
 for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {                                                 
      for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if (i==j){
         c <- merge(a,b)        
        } else 
              print("no result")
           }
                 }
```

I feel that in the loop I'm not able to specify that I am only working with row values from a single variable "Original_item" in df1

```
# df1 (4x4 matrix)
  Original_items        V2    V3   V4
  Love birds.            1     5    3
  Eat a lot of food.     2     5    5
  Love birthdays.        2     2    4
  Enjoy holidays.        4     1    3

# df2  (4x1 matrix)
  Reordered                   
  Enjoy holidays. 
  Eat a lot of food.
  Love birds. 
  Love birthdays.      

# df_desired (4x5 matrix)
  Reordered             Original_items            V2   V3   V4    
  Enjoy holidays.       Enjoy holidays.           4     1    3
  Eat a lot of food.    Eat a lot of food.        2     5    5 
  Love birds.           Love birds.               1     5    3
  Love birthdays.       Love birthdays.           2     2    4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Maybe just rename `Original_items` and merge?!

Comment: OP, please tell us how your question is more than a simple `merge`. See link in @NelsonGon's comment. Loops are unnecessary.

Comment: Dear Parfait, if you can suggest a solution that avoids loops, and can reproduce my example, please let me know, I would be grateful to hear it. I have checked the post suggested by NelsonGon, and tried various merger commands but to no avail. I see that I can merge df1 and df2 to produce df_desired, but how do you rearrange the data to replicate df_desired? Please show me possible syntax, I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you first want to sort `df1$original_items` to be in the same order as `df2` reorder, then apply that same sorting pattern to the rest of `df1` variables.
First get your vector of indices of `df1` in the sequential order that you desire those rows of `df1` to end up in.

```
#initialize an object to capture the above output
indices <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    indices[i] <- which(df1$Original_items == df2$Reordered[i]))
}
```

Then, just use this list of indices to reorder the all the rows of `df1` and create the new df.

```
df_desired <- cbind(df2$Reordered, df1[indices, ])
```

Comment: If you have multiple cases of each level in `df2` this gets a little tricker. In that case, you may be safe just wrapping the `which` statement in a call to `unique`, depending on your desired outcome.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! I found it helpful. There is some issue with the code as it does not reproduce the df_desired, as elements in the 'Original_items' and 'Reordered' variables" do not match. Could you please help me figure out the reason for that? Thank you

Comment: Oh sorry, good catch! I edited the answer above so that it df_desired correctly reorders df1 in the order of df2, not the other way around. The new loop is as follows: `indices[i] <- which(df1$Original_items == df2$Reordered[i])`

Comment: thank you so much, everything works perfectly now!!! I am extremely grateful for your help!

Comment: Cheers!! Glad to hear it.